# APYDataGridBundle - export a lot of data fails

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I have to export **50000** rows from a table to Excel (or CSV). In future, this would be million or even more. The export function was the reason why I choose this bundle, but now I see that was a mistake.

When there are more than a few thousand rows the bundle just fails. I think this is because of memory limit.

I found this:

```
public function computeData($grid)
    {
        $data = $this->getGridData($grid);

        $this->content = '<table border=1>';
        if (isset($data['titles'])) {
            $this->content .= '<tr>';
            foreach ($data['titles'] as $title) {
                $this->content .= sprintf("<th>%s</th>", htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES));
            }
            $this->content .= '</tr>';
        }

        foreach ($data['rows'] as $row) {
            $this->content .= '<tr>';
            foreach ($row as $cell) {
                $this->content .= sprintf("<td>%s</td>", htmlentities($cell, ENT_QUOTES));
            }
            $this->content .= '</tr>';
        }

        $this->content .= '</table>';
    }
```

It seems to get all data at once to one variable.

At least the bundle allows creating own Export class. Anyone know how this bundle allows to for example get data page by page? I think that should be enough. I can't find anywhere method to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resigned from using APY Grid, because its slow and every single thing I wanted to do was to much complicated.

So I decided to build the table using AngularJS. It took me something around 4 hours. Now it looks better and is faster.

Working with my own functions I am now able to export data just the way I want. For this i used StreamedResponse which is my discovery of the week. I paginate data, clear entity manager after each page and send page by page data to receiver. Dont matter what is the stage of script it use less than 20MB memory.

It now can handle bilions of rows.

So if anyone have the same problem I realy recommend do it this way :)